# Training a Neural Network on a rule of List

Tags: neural-networks

Is is possible to train this format of data?

```
{{21, 30, 39, 45, 46, 44}->{1, 5, 20, 28, 52, 24}
{31, 52, 36, 34, 26, 32}->{9, 47, 40, 34, 7, 11}
{48, 35, 44, 8, 45, 4}->{25, 30, 4, 28, 21, 35}
.
.
.
{15, 42, 49, 17, 44, 30}->{22, 11, 19, 23, 15, 18}}
```

Will a Neural Network learn these associations?

Thank You
Michel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is quite possible.

Let's create some example training data:

```
data = Table[Range[x, x + 4] -> N@Sin[Range[x, x + 4]], {x, 1, 10000}]
```

(so, for example, the first item in this dataset is `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} -> {0.841471, 0.909297, 0.14112, -0.756802, -0.958924}`)

Let's specify a network:

```
net =
 NetChain[{UnitVectorLayer[], BasicRecurrentLayer[100], 
   BasicRecurrentLayer[100], SequenceLastLayer[], LinearLayer[5]}]
```

And now we can train this:

```
trained = NetTrain[net, RandomSample[data], ValidationSet->Scaled[.1]]
```

(I `RandomSample` the data to put it in a random order)

[image: training in progress]

And now we can show how accurate the net is (or isn't):

```
ListLinePlot[{trained@data[[1, 1]], data[[1, 2]]}]
```

[image]

You will want to look at the documentation for `BasicRecurrentLayer`, `GatedRecurrentLayer`, `LongShortTermMemoryLayer`, and similar.